# Правильный редирект

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите пожалуйста сделать правильный редирект. Задача переводить на router.php аналогично

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php [L]
```

Но с учетом еще переброски http на https протокол

Например человек вводит: http://site.com/leaders?id=32. То его должно перекинуть на router.php c запросом https://site.com/leaders?id=32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Protocol} !=https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt ### кроме
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.xml ### кроме
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] ### любой запрос на https

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://your-site.com/router.php [L] ### с индекса на router
</IfModule>
```